# Can I ask a question related to various tools used in Robotic Process Automation?

Tags: discussion

Basically, I need to know what are the various tools, technologies that are used in Robotic Process Automation.

Answer (score 6):

At the risk of sounding blunt, based on what you wrote such a question would be both off-topic and too broad -- the latter very likely on *any* StackExchange site, even if the topic fits.

On the other hand, a question about a *specific* tool or technology involving scientific computing, that would be welcome here.

Comment: Thank You. I appreciate your view.

Comment: To add to this answer: basically, any type of "list question" asking for a review of a field is going to be too broad. As currently posed, a question asking for tools/technologies for Robotic Process Automation could require a review article or book to answer. In general, we want users to ask targeted questions that could be answered in a few sentences to maybe a page or two at most, hopefully supported by links or citations to references.